# How to avoid binding object in JS?

Tags: javascript, object

I am not sure what's going on with this, probably I am doing something wrong, but to be honest, I cannot see what's the point. Just take a look at this code and see what happens:

```
var object = {
  one: "one",
  two: "two"
};

var object2 = {}

object2 = object;

object["three"] = "what?"

console.log(object2);
```

The output for the `object2` should be `{one: "one", "two": two"}`, however it returns `{one: "one", "two": two", "three": "what?"}`

So why is this happening? I am not modifying `object2`, but it gets updated after the push of new value. How can I solve this? I just want to keep the `object2` like before. Thanks

Comment: After `object2 = object;`, both variable contain references to the very same object.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

object2 references object (points to the same reference in memory)

i assume you want to create object2 that is a copy of the first one, which you can do like this:

```
var obj2 = Object.assign({}, object);
```

or

```
var obj2 = {...object}
```

you can check [Object assign MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign), or just google about spread operator syntax

Comment: Now it works perfect. However, can you explain me a bit more why this happened? I still cannot understand it. Thanks!

Comment: JS has primitive (Boolean, Number, String, undefined, null) and reference types (Object, Array, Function). Yeah you can also wrap those primitives with their constructor like String('asd') so that is an object too and behaves differently from a primitive type... Basically when you said object2 = {}, at that point object2 was completely different object, but then after you said object2 = object which means that it should point to object so it holds the reference to that first object. Now when you change orig, the other changes too because it's pointing to that same first object, it is that obj.

Answer (score -1):

When you assign object to object2, it is reference is given to object2. Hence when you add  'three':'what?'  to object and print object2, it will be same.